# Count over a Group in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I need to create a query that counts over a `GROUP BY` clause. Specifically, 
over the `Order_ID` and `SUB_ID` columns and counts the number of `Product_IDs` per `Order_ID` and `SUB_ID`.

**It should look like this:**

[image]

However, the data is set up a little on the odd side and the only way to get the information (minus the Count column of course) is with:

```
SELECT
    tbl1.Order_Id
    ,tbl1.Sub_Id
    ,tbl1.Product_Id
    ,tbl1.Product_Value
    ,tbl2.Product_Owner
    ,tbl2.Owner_Id

FROM
tbl1 AS tbl1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tbl2 AS tbl2 ON tbl1.Order_Id=tbl2.Order_Id AND tbl1.Sub_Id=tbl2.Sub_Id
```

How would I add such a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT tbl1.Order_Id, tbl1.Sub_Id,
       COUNT(tbl1.Product_Id)
FROM tbl1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     tbl2
     ON tbl1.Order_Id = tbl2.Order_Id AND tbl1.Sub_Id = tbl2.Sub_Id
GROUP BY tbl1.Order_Id, tbl1.Sub_Id;
```

Because the query is returning rows only from `tbl1` and using a `LEFT JOIN`, you should be able to do:

```
SELECT tbl1.Order_Id, tbl1.Sub_Id,
       COUNT(tbl1.Product_Id)
FROM tbl1 
GROUP BY tbl1.Order_Id, tbl1.Sub_Id;
```

EDIT:

I see, that is sample data.  In that case, you probably just want `row_number()`:

```
SELECT tbl1.Order_Id, tbl1.Sub_Id, tbl1.Product_Id, tbl1.Product_Value,
       tbl2.Product_Owner, tbl2.Owner_Id
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tbl1.Order_Id, tbl1.Sub_Id ORDER BY tbl1.Product_Id) as seqnum
FROM tbl1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     tbl2 
     ON tbl1.Order_Id = tbl2.Order_Id AND
        tbl1.Sub_Id = tbl2.Sub_Id;
```

Comment: This returns the total count and I would like a cumulative count. But I like the idea of joining it on as a separate table.